# NSDateFormatter automatically get dateFormat (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Is there a way to get the dateFormat string automatically (without explicit setting it)?

```
     ///getting the date from datePicker
    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        timeFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy" ///get this automatically???
        dateTextField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }



         [...]///other stuff
           let dateString = dateTextField.text
           let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
           dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy" //can I get the string automatically based on user locale??? so I don't have to worry about setting the correct string?
           dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
           let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString!)
           print(dateFromString)/// gives nil if dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy" is commented out
```

Comment: what you get if you not set date formate?

Comment: I'm getting nil if I don't set it. If I do set it as above then I get my date correctly. BUT I want to get the string automatically based on user's preferences.

Comment: fetch user preference date formate

Comment: How do I fetch that please?

Comment: what the output you get here sender.date

Comment: always we need to mention the date format what we need

Comment: I see. So no way to get this automatically then. Something like dateFormatter.dateFormat = local.dateFormatSetByUser

Comment: no bro, how do we know tis comes in which format

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying this. I was under the impression that such a trivial thing would be already be set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can able to use the following ways to apply the date format automatically. The below code is in Swift 3.0.

**Way 1(Using Custom Date and Time Styles):**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "dd MMM yyyy", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

**Way 2(Using Preset):**

```
let dateString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none)
```

Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html) for more info.